# Copy Paste of text not working on MSoffice installed in PlayOn Linux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-word

I have installed MSOffice 2007 in Ubuntu 18.10. Copy and paste the text inside the MS word is not working. How could I enable it?